# Looking for a particular movie format

Tags: video, video-editing, educational

I'm looking for a program to learn which can easily create videos of a format similar to...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uKEG8RGRY8

A list of basic to advanced programs is preferred.

System = Windows.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details on your requirements.

Comment: I've added my list to your question. But it would be great if you would give us some feedback what operation system you have?

Comment: Windows will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Well it really depends on your operation system.

If you run a linux system, you can try to use **[OpenShot](http://www.openshot.org/)** which is really great if it works. I have used it for a while but I've encountered many crashes. As a start a good choice!

If you run a linux, mac or windows system you can try to run **[Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/)** which is great but not opensource and must be purchased. It's based on an subscription, which starts at ~20€ per month and goes to ~130€ for a year. A lifetime license costs above 300€. Maybe a bit over the top for your needs.

On mac and windows you can run **[Adobe PremierePro CC](http://www.adobe.com/de/products/premiere.html)** which runs in the cloud platform from adobe for a monthly price starting at ~20€ per month. It's a really great tool which much power. But maybe a bit over the top for the things you're trying.

Another suggestion is just to use **[Blender](http://www.blender.org/)** which is a 3D editing program but will provide you with all necessary tools to cut and modify videos too. It's just great, only a few mb in size and it's opensource and free of charge. The next good thing, it's available on windows, mac and linux and works and looks the same on all systems.

I hope this will help you to get a good overview. :-)